# is there any way to generate tokens

Tags: javascript, react-native, validation, firebase-authentication, token

in react native , I am building a students app and when the students use it they need to insert a code or token to unlock the content of it how I can do that , notice  the code will be printed on cards and the people who want it can buy it from teacher for example .

I need a way to generate token or some libraries that can do the thing just I need a token and validate it in the app to open the content for that person and then the token will be only used once and the app will open forever .

Comment: Option A: generate random tokens, store them in your database, look them up there. Option B: generate random tokens, sign them with a private key, validate their signatures. For both options, consider how you would deal with exceptions: someone lost the token they bought, someone shared their token with the public, your private key leaked, your database was breached, etc…